# Memory Size of an object as byte

Tags: java

If I have an object, for example...

```
String city = "Chicago"
```

and I have millions of them. Let's say I take the byte of those million objects,

```
byte[] cityByte = "Chicago".getBytes()
```

Would byte take less space in memory?

edit: more in-depth:

I have several [com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.Message](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/Message.java) objects. I intend to use [SerializationUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) from Apache Commons Lang to get the byte array of each object and store it in a List.

I was thinking that if I store 1 million Message objects in a List, that might cause an issue. But if I store the same million objects as a byte array in a List, I will have a little more memory left so I can do other stuff. Hence the question.

Comment: This depends on the characters in the strings and the encoding you use.

Comment: It depends on your JVM, your JVM options and your platform character encoding. I'd say that this solution is probably not the best one for your problem, but you haven't exposed your actual problem. Please do. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you have millions of strings in memory? Also, do you realize that not all objects have a getBytes() method?

Comment: If you have a lot of similar strings you can also save memory by using the JVM string pool.

Comment: @JBNizet I edited my question adding more info. Please have a look.

Comment: Do you already run into memory problems? If not, it sounds like premature optimization to me. If you do, isn't there a better way to scale in a cloud platform?

Comment: OK. So your question has absolutely nothing with String.getBytes(), but with the size of serialized objects vs. the size of objects. You're probably won't save anything, on the contrary, by serializing objects. And that still doesn't explain what you're trying to achieve with all those messages in memory. Messages are usually meant to be sent, processed or stored, but not kept in memory. Anyway, why do you think you'll have memory problems in the first place? Don't optimize prematuraly.

Comment: Hold on @Robert.  I thought cloud would only scale up if there were more request coming than a pod can handle. But it won't scale up if memory usage goes up? Am I correct?

Comment: In recent versions, Java already does a lot of optimization of identical strings that survive multiple garbage collection cycles by making them share the backing byte or character array. Your naive attempt at optimization will likely only consume more memory, not less.

Comment: Have you actually run into a memory problem? Most machines these days can handle a few million objects without breaking a sweat.

Comment: @JBNizet okay thanks. Yes I will store them in a database. But, I always thought that converting an object to byte is like encoding it, which would take less bytes in memory and that means less memory space. Perhaps I am wrong. Or maybe SerializationUtils of Apache Commons library is not doing any encoding hence memory size remains the same. Am I correct here?

Comment: Your data is already being stored as bytes in ram, doing this just convolutes everything.

Comment: @vandench okay thanks.

Comment: @MadPhysicist okay I will keep that in mind. Thanks for sharing this info.

Comment: Serialization in a high level language also typically involves adding tags for the various types, on a normal object that tag is just a pointer to a class definition, on serialized data it is typically a string.

Comment: It fields like this question still needs to be drilled down to explaining, in the post itself, not in comments, _why_ there are millions of these objects and what needs to be done for which "using `.getBytes()`" was imagined as the solution. Step back a moment and explain how you got to this question, because this is almost guaranteed an XY problem, where you need to do X, you figured Y would work, and now you're asking about Y rather than about how to achieve X with Y simply mentioned as "something you were thinking of".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I provided the **x** in the question under edit:

Comment: No, you didn't. You explained _what you have_, but not why - _Why_ do you need them byte serialized? If you have lots of data, then the immediate approach would be "I guess it's time for a database because putting this much data in volatile memory or flat files would be ridiculous". So: _what are you trying to achieve_ for which you have decided you need byte serialization? Because _that thing_ can almost certainly be done in a far better way than what you've thought of right now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes my first thought was to store it in a database. But my application will be used as a library and added to different microservices which use either MariaDB or MongoDB. I can take care of all the databases. Or I can just use redis cache. But, I thought that for the time being, till my manager approves redis cache approach, I can just store data in byte form in a .txt file. And read/write to it. But as of now, I am not worried about anything. All processing is happening in the memory. Once my manager comes back, I will ask her what should be the way forward.

Comment: Cool - but you've _still_ not explained what what you actually need to do that requires having a byte serialization at all, so I guess after this point you also don't know why you need them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: No. I thought storing thousands of messages in a text file as a byte would take less storage space. And loading them up into memory would be equally efficient. But I will only have 100 or 200 in memory at one point. So there wouldn't be any problem memory wise. Yes I do know there will be extra CPU utilization in serialization/deserialization, but I was ready for that cost. But this whole approach is abondoned. Regardless of x and y, I wanted to know the memory consumption of a simple String vs byte of that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used JOL[1](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) to determine the actual size of the objects in memory at runtime:

```
import org.openjdk.jol.info.GraphLayout;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String city = "Chicago";

        byte[] cityByte = "Chicago".getBytes();

        System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(city).toPrintable());
        System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(cityByte).toPrintable());
    }
}
```

output:

```
java.lang.String@4d7e1886d object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE             PATH                           VALUE
        76ac826d8         24 java.lang.String                                (object)
        76ac826f0         32 [C               .value                         [C, h, i, c, a, g, o]


[B@3caeaf62d object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE PATH                           VALUE
        76ac82738         24 [B                                  [67, 104, 105, 99, 97, 103, 111]
```

Conclusion: 'String' **32** bytes VS 'byte[]' **24** bytes

P.S. Results may vary depends on JVM version and options. Try the same approach in your environment. Run at jdk_1.8.0_161 Mac OS 10.14

[JOL](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/)